# To find mean in onedataframe for another dataframe id's using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Data frame 1:

```
Stationid
       10
       11
       12
       13
       14
       15
       16
       17
```

Data frame 2:

```
Stationid  Maintanance
       10           55
       15           38
       21          100
       10           56
       22          101
       15           39
       10           56
```

I need to calculate mean for station id's in dataframe 1 on dataframe 2

Expected output:

```
Stationid  Maintainance Mean
       10          55.666667
       15          38.500000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df2[df2['id'].isin(df1['Stationid'])].groupby('id', as_index=False)['Maintanance'].mean()
df.columns = ['Stationid','Maintainance Mean']
print (df)
   Stationid  Maintainance Mean
0         10          55.666667
1         15          38.500000
```

Comment: It works please upvote my question. I will tick the answer in 2 mins

Comment: @YogeshSP - Yes, I by default upvote all question what answering ;) So done ;)

Comment: How to find the standard deviation for the same?

Comment: @YogeshSP - then change `['Maintanance'].mean()` to `['Maintanance'].agg(['mean','std'])`

Comment: Without aggregate how can I have the condition as a separate dataframe

Comment: @YogeshSP - use `mask = df2['id'].isin(df1['Stationid'])` and then `df3 = df2[mask]` for matching values and `df4 = d2f[~mask]` for not matched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178337/discussion-between-yogesh-s-p-and-jezrael).